# Using IBM MobileFirst HTTP Adapters for web application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a hybrid mobile app, which is developed on **IBM MobileFirst Platform**. I have you HTTP adapters for rest api calls. Now i am planning to create a full scale web application in AngularJS 2.0 & BootStrap. Will it be possible to use those adapters in that web application? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

MobileFirst Foundation does not care for the technology used to create the  application... be it native or web. Ionic-based, Angular, Cordova etc... it doesn't matter.

Adapters sit on the server and you make a call to the server to use them... so it doesn't matter what you use in the client.

Comment: In mobile app i use  "WL.Client.invokeProcedure" and i mention which adapter to call, which procedure and the parameters to pass. How would i be able do this in the web application. I need to link the MobileFirst API Library to the project. Do you have any tutorials on this?

Comment: In your mobilefirst 7.1 project you  can add environments. One of these environments is Mobile Web or Desktop browser, depending on what you want to target... the APIs work the same eveywhere...

Comment: Does the Desktop browser work just like a web application?

Comment: Yes. Be aware that if using these environments in 7.1 you must disable "session independence" in worklight.properties. See the documentation.